# How old are they?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, puzzle

One man speaking to other:

When you were born I was 20 years old. Today I am twice the age you were when I was the age you are now.

What are the ages of both of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

80 and 60

I think it's helpful to break up and reword the problem:
"I am 20 years older than you."
"When I was your current age, you were (of course) 20 years younger than me."
"I am now twice the age you were at that time."

And I don't really know how I got from that, to 80. But it works:

Man A is 20 years older than man B.
When man A is 80, man B is 60.
When man A *was* 60, man B *was* 40.
"When I was your current age (60), you were 20 years younger than me (40)."
"I am now twice the age you were at that time (80)."

Comment: The way to get there is x-20 = y and x = 2 * (y-20)